# How can I get the Developer Visual working in Power BI?

Tags: powerbi

I want to learn how to create custom visualizations in Power BI. I am trying to follow various instructions like the one here (https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/tools/DebugVisualSetup.md) but when I go into PowerBI.com and click the Developer Visual button, I get "Can't connect visual server. Please make sure the visual server is running and configured correctly" error. It says you need to run "pbiviz start" in the command line in the root folder of your visual. I get an error when I do that too, but I don't even understand why we need to do that? That's on my local computer, how does that affect what's going on in powerbi.com? I just have a basic default custom visual setup locally.

The error I get when I run "pbiviz start":
[image]

I feel like I just need a push in the right direction, because I'm not understanding this conceptually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. The line where it says Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::8080 meant that I had another web service thing running on port 8080. I opened up Resource Manager on my Windows machine and went to Listening Ports and found TNSLSNR running under port 8080, which is some Oracle thing I do not need running- I shut it down by finding it in my Services list. Then ran "pbiviz start" and it worked! The developer visual also showed up in powerbi.com.